# Silent failure when attempting to add a login that is used by a different account on a different site

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

#### Steps to Replicate

1. Create a new Stack Overflow account, [Test A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422922/test-a), using OpenID.SE with the email `jeremy+test+a@jeremybanks.ca`.
2. Create a new Programmers.SE account, [Test B](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/55124/test-b), using OpenID.SE with the email `jeremy+test+b@jeremybanks.ca`.)
3. Attempt to add the OpenID.SE login with the email `jeremy+test+b@jeremybanks.ca` to the Stack Overflow account Test A.

#### Expected Result

The user would be prompted to merge the two Stack Exchange accounts or an error message would be displayed.

#### Actual Result

The user is redirected as though the login was added successfully, but it is not actually added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed. Such accounts are now merged. The first time I tried, it took a few minutes for the merge to take effect. In the meanwhile one of the accounts' "my logins" popup displayed a 404 error:

[image]

The accounts were merged instantly the second time I tried.

Comment: This simply does not work for me. And I only have a single Google account. I log in using Yahoo and try to add a Google login and it seems to silently succeed but then "my logins" never shows it.