# Why can't I merge my two accounts?

Tags: bug, merge-accounts

This process is not working for me:

1. Go to profile page
2. Press "my logins". Empty list.
3. I press "add more logins..."
4. I press "log in with StackExchange"
5. It asks

   ```
   Confirm
   This login is new to Bitcoin - Stack Exchange:
   Stack Exchange (vi0oss@gmail.com)
   This login has been seen on the following sites:
   Stack Overflow
   Server Fault
   ... and 15 more.
   Do you want to add this login to your Bitcoin - Stack Exchange account?
   ```
6. I press "Add login". It returns to the home page.
7. I go to profile and open "my logins". Still empty list.

#### What should happen:

Accounts got merged, like on unix.stackexchange.com, or meaningful error message displayed on some step.

#### What happens:

Add operation looks like if it is succeed, but actually produces no effect.

Comment: I *think* this is a duplicate of my previous bug report [Silent failure when attempting to add a login that is used by a different account on a different site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114455/silent-failure-when-attempting-to-add-a-login-that-is-used-by-a-different-accoun)

Comment: Something similar, but only one email address involved in this case. Maybe it also happens if you already asked one question before registering.

Comment: Ah, the original account on Bitcoin.SE was an unregistered (no login) account?

Comment: Yes. Seems like when I first "register" then ask question it's OK. But if I first I ask question (filling display name, site and email (the same as in main account)) then "register", the problem happens.

Comment: Looks like as time passed the accounts became merged and the "my logins" list showing what it should show.